# incorrect impagination with data extracted from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a problem of visualization of data extracted from a Database, that then goes in a Json file. When i view the page, the data is visualized incorrectly in the table. Here is the code:

HTML code: here we have a table with the first static row, and the others that are dynamic.

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1 div-1">
<table class="datatable table table-primary table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Cognome</td>
        <td>Indirizzo</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Tipo contatto</td>
        <td>Telefono 1</td>
        <td>Telefono 2</td>
        <td>Telefono 3</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tab-0">
    <!--inserimento dinamico contenuti-->
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--spazio per il form-->
```

Then, we have the PHP code:

```
 private $hookUp;
 private $sql;
 private $sql2;
 private $sql3;
 private $sql4;

 public function __construct()
 {
 $this->hookUp = UniversalConnect::doConnect();

$this->sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
$this->sql2 = "SELECT * FROM accettazione";
$this->sql3 = "SELECT * FROM riparazione";
$this->sql4 = "SELECT * FROM operatore";

// Tabella cliente

$response = array();
$data = array();

if ($result = $this->hookUp->query($this->sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

        $data[] = array("id" => "<tr class='row'><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>",
                        "nome" => "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>",
                        "cognome" => "<td>" . $row['cognome']. "</td>",
                        "indirizzo" => "<td>" . $row['indirizzo'] . "</td>",
                        "email" => "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>",
                        "tipo_contatto" => "<td>" . $row['tipo_contatto'] . "</td>",
                        "telefono_1" => "<td>" . $row['telefono_1'] . "</td>",
                        "telefono_2" => "<td>" . $row['telefono_2'] . "</td>",
                        "telefono_3" => "<td>" . $row['telefono_3'] . "</td></tr>");

        $response['cliente'] = $data;

        $fp = fopen("../lista.json", "w");
        fwrite($fp,json_encode($response));
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

This is the code that reads the data and appends it to the HTML page:

```
 var name;
 var value;

 var count_cliente = 0;
 var count_accettazione = 0;
 var count_riparazione = 0;
 var count_operatore = 0;

 $('.sidebar-menu a').click(function (e) {
     hideContentDivs();
var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
$(".main-sections div").eq(tmp_div).show();

$.getJSON("lista.json", function (json) {

    if (tmp_div == 0) {
        var data = json.cliente;

        if (count_cliente == 0) {

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var obj = data[i];

                for (var key in obj) {
                    name = key;
                    value = obj[key].toString();

                    $("#tab-0").append(name + " : " + value);
                }
            }
            count_cliente++;
        }
```

Finally we have the Json data that should dinamically form the row:

```
 {
     "cliente": [
         {
             "id": "<tr class='row'><td>1</td>",
             "nome": "<td>Nome</td>",
             "cognome": "<td>Cognome</td>",
             "indirizzo": "<td>Indirizzo</td>",
             "email": "<td>Nome@provider.it</td>",
             "tipo_contatto": "<td>email</td>",
             "telefono_1": "<td>1234</td>",
             "telefono_2": "<td>4321</td>",
             "telefono_3": "<td>9890</td></tr>"
         }
     ],
     "accettazione": [
         {
             "id": "<tr class='row'><td>1</td>",
             "data": "<td>2015-07-30</td>",
             "id_operatore": "<td>1</td>",
             "dispositivo": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "note": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "password": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "tipo_avviso": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "id_cliente": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "difetto_dichiarato": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "codice": "<td>1234567890</td></tr>"
         }
     ],
     "riparazione": [
         {
             "id": "<tr class='row'><td>1</td>",
             "stato": "<td>asdf</td>",
             "note_riparazione": "<td>asdf</td>",
             "data_riconsegna": "<td>2015-07-06</td>",
             "riconsegnato": "<td>0</td>",
             "difetto_riscontrato": "<td></td>",
             "tag": "<td>asdf</td>",
             "urgente": "<td>1</td>",
             "id_accettazione": "<td>12</td>",
             "id_operatore": "<td>1</td></tr>"
         }
     ],
     "operatore": [
         {
             "id": "<tr class='row'><td>1</td>",
             "nome": "<td>Nome</td>",
             "cognome": "<td>Cognome</td>",
             "username": "<td>a.Cognome</td>",
             "password": "<td>Password</td>",
             "email": "<td>a.Cognome@provider.it</td>",
             "telefono": "<td>1234567890</td>",
             "categoria": "<td>user</td></tr>"
         },
         {
             "id": "<tr class='row'><td>2</td>",
             "nome": "<td>Nome</td>",
             "cognome": "<td>Cognome</td>",
             "username": "<td>qwerty</td>",
             "password": "<td>DIT2013SIS</td>",
             "email": "<td>qwerty@provider.it</td>",
             "telefono": "<td>987654321</td>",
             "categoria": "<td>admin</td></tr>"
         }
     ]
 }
```

If I inspect the dynamically generated row with Firebug, i find that the row is printed in this way:

```
 <tr>
 <td>Id</td>
 </tr>
 <td>Data</td> [...]
```

But the closing tr tag should be at the end of the row.

What's the problem, could you help me to understand the error?

Comment: Can you show us your database looks like the data has html code inside.

Comment: I can't show the DB, anyway i haven't found other solutions...if i have to pass the data to the tbody, what other solutions could i use, assuming that i can't print php code directly in my page but i have to use Ajax? Otherwise, if i append data to the tr tag, i will have a neverending sequence of td tags, and the row will never end.

Comment: i've solved. thanks the same. i had to write the "output" var differently in the js code